# objects becomes null in the draw() function in the processing

Tags: processing

I have 2 print statements below. first print statement is working fine but the second print is returning a null value. what could be the reason.

Thanks in advance.

```java
void setup()

{
setSize(800);
GUI g=new GUI();
Println(g); // this prints fine
}
void draw()
{
Println(g); //this becomes null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, please post the actual code you're running. The `println()` function starts with a lower-case letter, so the code you've posted won't compile. Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Secondly, please understand how scope works. Variables you create in one function are not available in other functions. So the `g` variable you create in the `setup()` function is not the same as the `g` variable in the `draw()` function!

All of that being said, your problem is caused by the fact that Processing contains a `g` variable that you aren't really supposed to mess with. Change the name of the variable to avoid this problem. Of course, this will give you a compiler error because you're trying to use a variable outside of its scope. Fix that by declaring variables you want to use in multiple functions at the top of your sketch.